# Big queryの2つのテーブルにあるテキストを比較→最も近いテキストをCSV形式で出力したい

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

Big queryのテーブルにあるテキストを比較し最も近いもの同士をマッチさせて
CSVで出力したいと考えています。

Big queryの知識とdifflibに関する知識が浅いため、Pythonに詳しい方がいましたら
教えていただけますと幸いです。以下が試したことになります。

**1．Big queryにテーブルstringsA, strinsBを2つ作成**

stringsA

| id | name | title | description | latitude | longtitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | たか歯科 | null | null | 35.1636963 | 136.884171 |
| 2 | ホワイトニングクリニックtanaka | null | null | 35.1704369 | 136.879532 |
| 3 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | null | null | 37.952049 | 139.113178 |

stringsB

| id | name | title | description | latitude | longtitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | たか歯科 品川院 | null | null | 35.1636963 | 136.884171 |
| 2 | ホワイトニングクリニック Tanaka | null | null | 35.1704369 | 136.879532 |
| 3 | bbbbbbbbb | null | null | 37.94230 | 139.12345 |

**2．テーブルstringsAのB列にあるnameを、stringsBのB列にあるnameと比較**
**3. stringsAにあるテキストに最も近いstringsBの文字列をCSVで出力**
出力されるCSVのイメージはこちら

| stringsA | stringsB | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| たか歯科 | たか歯科 品川院 | 0.4166666667 |
| ホワイトニングクリニックtanaka | ホワイトニングクリニック Tanaka | 0.9189189189 |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |  | 0 |

以上を実現するために下記のようなコードを書きました。

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from difflib import get_close_matches, SequenceMatcher
import csv
key_path = 'KEY_PATH'
credentials =  service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"], #https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes
)


stringsA = ('''
SELECT　*　FROM `stringsA`
''')

stringsB = ('''
SELECT　*　FROM `stringsB`
''')


client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project=credentials.project_id,
)
query_job = client.query(stringsA)
rows = query_job.result()

#### リスト b から一番類似している文字列を抽出し、
#### その類似度を取得し、それらをリストとして返す関数を定義。
#### 類似度の足切り率はデフォルトを最低にして、変更出来るようにしておく
def closest(x, rate=0.01):
    result = get_close_matches(x, stringsB, n=1, cutoff=rate)
    if len(result) <= 0:
        return [x, None, 0.0]
    result = result[0]
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, x, result)
    return [x, result, s.ratio()]

#### リスト a のデータ全てを順番に処理するリスト内包表記
data = [closest(s) for s in stringsA]

#### csvファイルとして出力(encoding等は必要に応じて変更)
with open('closest02.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(['stringsA','stringsB','類似度'])
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

ただ、出力されるCSVは以下のようになってしまい
想定している結果になりません。

| stringsA | stringsB | 類似度 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1 |
| S |  | 0 |
| E |  | 0 |
| L |  | 0 |
| E |  | 0 |

少し長くわかりずらいかもしれません。
以上となりますが、情報不足等ありましたら申し訳ございません。
その際はご指摘していただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `query_job = client.query(stringsB)`がない (テーブル作成していない)のでは？
結果も `rows`のまま `stringsA` とか `stringsB` ではないし。

Comment: 複数の手順を順番にこなさなければならない所を、まとめて1つの質問にしようとするから混乱して先に進めないのでしょう。`1.BigQueryでデータを取得する。`, `2.取得したデータの内容を把握する。`, `3.取得したデータを後の処理(前回の質問)で対処可能な形に変換する。`, `4.形を整えたデータを処理する。` という切り分けた手順の各ステップで、正常に処理出来たかどうかを確認してみてください。